# How to prevent CommandLineRunner run() method exectution based on active spring profile being used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing Springboot app with Spring Data JPA and I use two application.properties defining **development** and **production** profiles.

My **production** profile uses real database.

My **development** profile uses an H2 database.

I determine which profile to use be setting `spring.profiles.active` flag in application.properties file.

The app also uses `CommandLineRunner` to pre-populate my H2 database with some data.

**I don't want my `CommandLineRunner` to do same for production database.**

How do I ensure `CommandLineRunner` will execute only in my **development** environment (when I set active profile to be development profile with `spring.profiles.active=development`)?

All google is giving me is the way to do same for tests but I dont want that.  I want to be able to prevent `CommandLineRunner` from executing its run() method based on current spring profile.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a development profile annotation to your runner. This way the runner will only run when the active profile(s) includes **development**

```
@Component
@Profile("development")
public class H2Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually does not work me but for some reason I thought it does.  I have 3 `application.properties` files.  `application.properties` sets `spring.profiles.active=prod` (or `dev`).  Then I have `application-dev.profile` and `application-prod.profile`.  So, I annotate my `CommandLineRunner` with `@Profile("dev")` since my `spring.profiles.active=prod` is set to `prod`.  Based on this, I would expect that the `CommandLineRunner run()` method is not called but it is still executed even thought I set `spring.profiles.active=prod`.

Comment: The best would be to confirm the which profile is actually set. When a Spring app starts up you will see a log line `The following profiles are active` If one of those profiles listed is `development` then your component will be loaded and executed
Another way is to autowire `Environment` in your component and then print out `environment.getActiveProfiles()` to ensure `development` is not included.
Also going back to basics and having just one properties file so there is no mistake which profile is set

Comment: That is correct, I have `The following profiles are active: prod`, yet the `CommandLineRunner run()` method still executes and fails but that is to expect since my entity is `@Immutable`.  But I would expect it not to be called since my `CommandLineRunner` is annotated with `@Profile("dev")`.  That means it should only execute when `dev` profile is active.